# User input commands in Console application

Tags: c#, console-application

I would like my console application to have commands like user types `/help` and console writes help. I would like it to use `switch` like:

```
switch (command)
{
    case "/help":
        Console.WriteLine("This should be help.");
        break;

    case "/version":
        Console.WriteLine("This should be version.");
        break;

    default:
        Console.WriteLine("Unknown Command " + command);
        break;
}
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/acy3edy3.aspx

Comment: What's the problem with this code? Do you know how to read a string from `Console`? That's the only thing you are missing, really. That, and a loop around the read and the switch.

Comment: The code is okay but I don't know how to loop the read... New to c#

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Based on your comment to [errata's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18007305/62576), it appears you want to keep looping until you're told not to do so, instead of getting input from the command line at startup. If that's the case, you need to loop outside the `switch` to keep things running. Here's a quick sample based on what you wrote above:

```
namespace ConsoleApplicationCSharp1
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string command;
        bool quitNow = false;
        while(!quitNow)
        {
           command = Console.ReadLine();
           switch (command)
           {
              case "/help":
                Console.WriteLine("This should be help.");
                 break;

               case "/version":
                 Console.WriteLine("This should be version.");
                 break;

                case "/quit":
                  quitNow = true;
                  break;

                default:
                  Console.WriteLine("Unknown Command " + command);
                  break;
           }
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines might work:

```
// cmdline1.cs
// arguments: A B C
using System;
public class CommandLine
{
   public static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       // The Length property is used to obtain the length of the array. 
       // Notice that Length is a read-only property:
       Console.WriteLine("Number of command line parameters = {0}",
          args.Length);
       for(int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Arg[{0}] = [{1}]", i, args[i]);
       }
   }
}
```

run the command: cmdline1 A B C

Output:

```
 Number of command line parameters = 3
    Arg[0] = [A]
    Arg[1] = [B]
    Arg[2] = [C]
```

I don't do c# much(any) anymore but hope this helps.

Comment: This is not what I am looking for... I want user to type in Console Application a command like `/help` and Console writes other commands...

Answer (score -1):

There exist  .open source projects like http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/63374/C-NET-Command-Line-Argument-Parser-Reloaded that take care of this. Why reinventing the wheel?

Comment: I know that, but I want something simple like using `switch`